# xcode Address Sanitizer stopping app from crashing

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, frameworks, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to debug an crash in an app which results in this error

> libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc:
> std::bad_alloc dyld4 config:
> DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot

When I try to use Address Sanitizer to get more info it causes the app not to crash.
What could be the cause of this?

I also get this

> malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved
> vm space.

in the console with AS turned on.

Comment: try using a debugger instead of an address sanitizer

Comment: you could try to use a combination of valgrind and gdb to locate the problem, see [here](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver)